# Unable to instantiate activity - no empty constructor

Tags: android, android-activity

I have encounter the following error when the activity was called - Unable to instantiate activity.

In a nutshell I have two activity pages. The first one produces a list of array items populated through JSON data, and the second one (this one) provides more detailed information about one of the item clicked on the previous activity (activity one).

Below is the error message I receive from logcat after an item has been clicked from the first activity (list of arrays).

```
08-04 22:13:40.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1243):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 2681
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dooba.beta/com.dooba.beta.EventSingleItemActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.dooba.beta.EventSingleItemActivity; no empty constructor
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.dooba.beta.EventSingleItemActivity; no empty constructor
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
08-04 23:17:42.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     ... 11 more
```

Below is the code for the single item activity

```
public class EventSingleItemActivity extends Activity {

    public long id;
    public Uri list_item_bac;
    public String list_item_name;
    public String list_item_description;
    public String list_item_price;

    public EventSingleItemActivity(long id, Uri list_item_bac, String list_item_name, String list_item_description,String list_item_price){
        this.id = id;
        this.list_item_bac = list_item_bac;
        this.list_item_name = list_item_name;
        this.list_item_description = list_item_description;
        this.list_item_price = list_item_price;
    }
}
```

Below is the code for the activity that populates the entire list of arrays

```
public class EventsActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String URL_WEB_SERVICE = "http://dooba.ca/analytics/ed.php";
    private GridView gv;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> container;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> items;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events_list_layout);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        container = new ArrayList<Events_List>();
        //download JSON
        listDownload();


        GridView s = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        s.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EventsActivity.this,EventSingleItemActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id_item", id);//this is id of the item that you said it. for example id:5544323 from your JSON web service
                intent.putExtra("position", position); //order position in listview 0-1-2-3...
                startActivity(intent); //start Activity
            }
        });
    }
    public void listDownload(){
        RequestQueue volley = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_WEB_SERVICE, null, ResponseListener(), ErrorListener());
        volley.add(json);
    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> ResponseListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //your JSON Array
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list_item");
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                        container.add(convertirAnuncio(array.getJSONObject(i)));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                gv.setAdapter(new AdapterEvents(getApplicationContext(),container));
                }
            };
        };


    private Response.ErrorListener ErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
        };
    }

    //object JSON
    private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
        String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); 
        String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
        String list_item_price = obj.getString("list_item_price");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));
        return new Events_List(id,list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price, uri);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your support

**Update**

```
public class EventSingleItemActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    String list_item_name;
    String list_item_description;
    String list_item_price;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_single_item);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        list_item_name = i.getStringExtra("list_item_name");
        list_item_description = i.getStringExtra("list_item_description");
        list_item_price = i.getStringExtra("list_item_price");

        TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
        TextView txtprice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);

        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtname.setText(list_item_name);
        txtdescription.setText(list_item_description);
        txtprice.setText(list_item_price);


    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/price" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_head"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update 2**

```
public class EventsActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String URL_WEB_SERVICE = "http://dooba.ca/analytics/ed.php";
    private GridView gv;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> container;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> items;
    public Uri list_item_bac;
    public String list_item_name;
    public String list_item_description;
    public String list_item_price;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events_list_layout);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        container = new ArrayList<Events_List>();
        //download JSON
        listDownload();


        GridView s = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        s.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EventsActivity.this,EventSingleItemActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("list_item_name", list_item_name);
                intent.putExtra("list_item_description", list_item_description);
                intent.putExtra("list_item_price",list_item_price);

                startActivity(intent); //start Activity
            }
        });
    }
    public void listDownload(){
        RequestQueue volley = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_WEB_SERVICE, null, ResponseListener(), ErrorListener());
        volley.add(json);
    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> ResponseListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //your JSON Array
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list_item");
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                        container.add(convertirAnuncio(array.getJSONObject(i)));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                gv.setAdapter(new AdapterEvents(getApplicationContext(),container));
                }
            };
        };


    private Response.ErrorListener ErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
        };
    }

    //object JSON
    private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
        String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); 
        String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
        String list_item_price = obj.getString("list_item_price");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));
        return new Events_List(id,list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price, uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete your constructor from `EventSingleItemActivity`. Instead, retrieve your extras from `onCreate()` of `EventSingleItemActivity`, by calling `getIntent()` to get the `Intent` that created the activity instance.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. The EventSingleItemActivity page have been redone with the getIntent method. I no longer receive such error, but it does not seem to have worked. In the sense that a blank activity is shown. I have also included the XML code under the update section of my initial post. If you could kindly advise, than I would gladly appreciate.

Comment: @user3827788: You cannot retrieve an extra that you have not set. IOW, your `putExtra()` and `get...Extra()` calls must line up. Yours do not, as you are setting `id_item` and `position` but are trying to get `list_item_name` and such.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have updated the code under updated 2 of my initial post. Unfortunately, the issue still persist.